# Python loop over 2 files at the same time

Tags: python, loops

I have 2 CSV files of varying lengths.  I'm looking for a pythonic way to loop over both of them, pulling data from predefined columns and append that data to my 2 list respectively.

So data from f1 goes to list_A and data from f2 goes to list_B

I realise using zip wont work as the number of rows in each file is different.

```
list_A = []
list_B = []


with open(file_1,'r') as f1, open(file_2,'r') as f2:
    csvFile_1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
    csvFile_2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',')

    for x,y in zip(csvFile_1, csvFile_2):
        list_A.append(x[1])
        list_B.append(y[0])
```

Any pointers appreciated..

Comment: Why iterate both as once ? any reason to not use pandas lib ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to read them with `zip`, read them independently

```
with open(file_1, 'r') as f1, open(file_2, 'r') as f2:
    list_A = [x[1] for x in csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')]
    list_B = [x[0] for x in csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',')]
```

---

Or use `pandas` library

```
import pandas as pd

list_A = pd.read_csv(file_1, sep=',').iloc[:, 1].to_list()
list_B = pd.read_csv(file_2, sep=',').iloc[:, 0].to_list()
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, that does the trick.. I didn't want to use pandas as it was overkill for what I needed but your first solution works great for me... Thanks again

Comment: @blupacetek pandas is not an overkill way, that is a performant lib and good even for small things

Comment: Ok thanks ill give it a try :-)